# cannot use workaround for python PMML Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pmml

I'm trying to build a simple preprocessing Pipeline for a clustering model that uses K-Means and export it to PMML format.
I manage to make the Pipeline work but can't manage to finally export it to pmml.
I have divided the pipeline in two steps, handle numerical data and handle categorical data.

```
numeric_features = ['column1','column2','column3']

categorical_features = ['column4','column5']

num_mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([([numeric_column],SimpleImputer(strategy='median')) for numeric_column in numeric_features] 
    ,df_out=True,default=None)

categorical_mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([([categorical_column],LabelBinarizer()) for categorical_column in categorical_features]
,df_out=True,default=None)

pipeline = PMMLPipeline(steps=[
    ('num_mapper',num_mapper),
    ('cat_mapper',categorical_mapper)
])
```

Note that i have setted default to None in the first dataFrameMapper since it allows the output dataframe to preserve columns that haven't been selected (columns that indeed will be needed by the second mapper).

These workarounds work ok, the problem comes later when i try to export the pipeline to PMML

```
sklearn2pmml.sklearn2pmml(pipeline,'mypath')
```

This line of code yields the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'sklearn_pandas.dataframe_mapper.DataFrameMapper.default' has a missing (None/null) value
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.PyClassDict.get(PyClassDict.java:46)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.PyClassDict.getObject(PyClassDict.java:97)
```

I know this error is probably generated by the fact that i'm setting default to None in both DataFrameMappers, but the thing is it was the only workaround i found in order to preserve the columns needed for the second mapper. 
Is there any other workaround I could use? I know i could do all the transformations in the first DataFrameMapper but I don't like that idea since I want to separate numerical transformation from categorical transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Recently could kinda understand the use of FeatureUnion, and realized it could be an elegant solution.
Create the same mappers

```
numeric_features = ['column1','column2','column3']

categorical_features = ['column4','column5']

num_mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([([numeric_column],SimpleImputer(strategy='median')) for numeric_column in numeric_features] 
  )

categorical_mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([([categorical_column],LabelBinarizer()) for categorical_column in categorical_features])

preprocessing = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[('num_mapper',num_mapper),('cat_mapper',categorical_mapper)])

pipeline = PMMLPipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessing',preprocessing)
])

sklearn2pmml.sklearn2pmml(pipeline,'mypath')
```

With this workaround even managed to avoid the use of df_out and default flags in the function call.

Comment: In your question you have a pipeline where one DataFrameMapper follows another - this doesn't work. FeatureUnion lets you have both DataFrameMappers as the "first step" of the pipeline - this works. Why don't you simply combine those two DataFrameMappers into one? Alternatively, you could replace DataFrameMapper with `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`.